# how to -- url mapping in filter?

Tags: struts2, struts

I already have an unaswered question here that how and when .do is appended in any url when we use servlets...

Today when i learnt about filters, another doubt occured:

```
<filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
```

In this case what is /*, if it means that it will check all the requests? Besides when an action is invoked the `url says: http://..../myapp/register.action.` Like `.do`,  `.action` is appended and it is not even mentioned in mapping. Please clear this doubt and if possible the `.do` doubt also...

Comment: Yes, it checks all requests. The mapping has *nothing* to do with URL generation. The S2 tags generate the complete URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets try to clear your doubts one by one.The below line in web.xml

```
<filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

is an entry to invoke the S2 filter. line `<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>`, tells the container (tomcat/weblogic etc) that when container should invoke the filter.
Since for S2 we need to do a lot of initialization work in order for your application to work, we are telling the container that each request being sent to the container should go through the S2 filter.

Regarding the extension of the URL like `.action,.do`, this is S2 internal and nothing to do with the filter-mapping you have seen in `web.xml`.

So in short if you hit the url like

```
yourapplication-domian/abc.action
yourapplication-domian/abc.do
yourapplication-domian/abc.jsp
```

all those above request will be passed through the filter and now once they pass through the filter , S2 internally will check which URL is valid S2 URL 
for e.g if you have set extension as `.action` S2 will recognize only the URL with those extension and will process them while filter will process all.

Hope this will help you to clear your doubts

Answer (score 0):

Find struts-default.properties in struts-core jar there you can find these settings.

You may provide a comma separated list,

e.g. `struts.action.extension=action,jnlp,do`

```
   struts.action.extension=action (default setting)
```

Comment: where to find this file ? struts-core.jar ?